# Multiple selection of row swift

Tags: swift

I am using a tableView to display data of users, I want to enable multiple user selection and for now it malfunctions in such that when I deselect a selected user, the user details still remains in the array which I am storing it inside. how can I fix this. below is my code currently

```
struct ChatUser {
   var id: String
var name: String
}

var selectedUser: [ChatUser] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if self.selectedUser.contains(self.users[indexPath.row]) {
            let myIndex = self.selectedUser.index(of: self.users[indexPath.row])
            self.selectedUser.remove(at: myIndex!)
        } else {
            self.selectedUser.append(self.users[indexPath.row])
        }

        selectedUser.forEach { (user) in
            print("SELECTD \(user.id)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your ChatUSer model?

Comment: @King you can use `didDeselectRowAt` method for remove the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For removing your selected data for multi selection you can use `didDeselectRowAt` method of tableview delegate.

```
 struct ChatUser {
       var id: String
    var name: String
    }

    var selectedUser: [ChatUser] = []

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            self.selectedUser.append(self.users[indexPath.row])

            selectedUser.forEach { (user) in
                print("SELECTD \(user.id)")
            }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {   
           if self.selectedUser.contains(self.users[indexPath.row]) {
                let myIndex = self.selectedUser.index(of: self.users[indexPath.row])
                self.selectedUser.remove(at: myIndex!)
            }
    }
```

Comment: This works but I have a search bar in my navigation controller, when I click the search bar, the selected checkmarks disappear and if I select it there and close the searchbar, the check marks clear too

Comment: I only did regular cell for row at index path to display all the users when it is in the search form

Comment: @King then you need to put on bool for selection if it's true then show selection on that cell

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: @King crate one bool variable in structure change it's value on selection and deselection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191536/discussion-between-chirag-shah-and-king).

Answer (score 2):

One thing to ensure here is that the struct is equatable

```
extension ChatUser: Equatable {

    static func == (lhs: ChatUser, rhs: ChatUser) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

This is why your `.contains` and `.indexOf` are not working properly

Comment: so how do I now use this?

Comment: @King Just add this extension below you chat model, it will work automatically, assuming is the only thing not working.